# The order of prototype assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

From my reading about prototypes, I was under the impression that changes to a constructor function's prototype would be reflected throughout all objects that were created using that constructor function.

Consider this code:

```
var Class1 = function(){
    this.prop1 = 'value1';
};
Class1.prototype.prop2 = 'value2';

var Class2 = function(){
    this.prop3 = 'value3';
};

//Class2.prototype = new Class1(); //1*
var obj1 = new Class2();
Class2.prototype = new Class1(); //2*

console.log('1 ' + obj1.prop1); // undefined
console.log('2 ' + obj1.prop2); // undefined
console.log('3 ' + obj1.prop3); // value3
```

As you can see, because I assigned the Class1 prototype to Class2 after I had constructed obj1, then values of prop1 and prop2 are returning 'undefined'.
If you uncomment 1* and comment out 2*, the results are as expected.

I've done a fair bit of reading about prototypes over the last couple of days and no one has mentioned that the order is important.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course order is important because the `new` keyboard forces ECMAscript to return a fresh and newly created `Object` which has its `prototype` bound to whatever parent object. So the second you create an instance of your "Class" object (the term Class really has no place at all in ECMAscript) the engine must be aware of the prototype chain.

Comment: There's no of course about it. I'm from a .NET background and I've had plenty of assumptions destroyed so far. You explain that a fresh new Object is created and the prototype is bound at the time the 'new' keyword is used. I know this and I could just as easily assume that modifying the contents of the prototype after the object was created would be ignored by said object. This is not the case. As far as I know, the prototype is a reference that can be pointed to any old object at any time. This seems not to be the case. Any suggestions for a site that explains it?